# Parasoft error: objects to manage resources should be used instead "x" pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, parasoft

I've created a binary search tree, each node of my binary tree is setup in a struct containing the key, and a pointer to the left and right nodes.

In my copy constructor for this binary search tree, I call a helper method to recurs through the tree that looks like so:

```
Node* BinaryTree::copyHelper(const Node* other)
{
if(other == NULL)
{
    return NULL; // If there's no Node to copy, return NULL.
}

Node* newNode  = new Node; 

if(newNode)
{
    newNode->name  = other->name;
    newNode->left  = copyHelper(other->left); 
    newNode->right = copyHelper(other->right);
}

return newNode; 
}
```

My error mentioned in the title is on the left and right pointers in the final if statement above.

If someone could tell me how to remove it, that would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ parasoft error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388357/c-parasoft-error)

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that, it doesn't really help me.

Comment: Why not? Have you tried using smart pointers instead of raw pointers?

Comment: Seems like std::unique_ptr would be perfect for this.

Comment: std::unique_ptr <Node> NodePtr; NodePtr newNode(new Node); like so? I think my syntax is wrong as I'm getting an error.

Comment: It should be `typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> NodePtr; NodePtr newNode(new Node);`

Comment: Thank you, can I not return pointers of this type?

return newNode; 

Throws an error, converting NodePtr to type node *

Comment: @LewisElliott why don't you return a NodePtr?

Comment: @LewisElliott you'll need to post a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably bypass the warning if you use smart pointers instead of raw pointers:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> NodePtr; 
NodePtr newNode(new Node);
```

instead of

```
Node* newNode = newNode;
```