# How to return a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a key, and a pointer to left and right nodes defined in a struct, in a class for a binary search tree.

I was getting parasoft errors within the copy helper function of the class, so was advised to change the code to:

```
BinaryTree::Node* BinaryTree::copyHelper(const Node* other)
{
    if(other == NULL)
    {
        return NULL; // If there's no Node to copy, return NULL.
    }
    else
    {
        //Node* newNode  = new Node; 

        typedef std::unique_ptr<Node> NodePtr;  
        NodePtr newNode(new Node); 

        if(newNode)
        {
            newNode->name  = other->name;
            newNode->left  = copyHelper(other->left); 
            newNode->right = copyHelper(other->right);
        }

        return newNode;
    }
}
```

Now I am getting an error on the return statement of the newNode:

> IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from `NodePtr` to `BinaryTree::Node *`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you check your code sample please, at the moment your definition of `newNode` won't compile.

Comment: the ctor of unique_ptr is explicit

Comment: what do you want to return, `unique_ptr<Node>` or `Node*`? If you want Node*, then it does not need to have NodePtr in your function.

Comment: I used to use Node* newNode  = new Node; but have been told to use the new bit of code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414869/parasoft-error-objects-to-manage-resources-should-be-used-instead-x-pointer I still want to return what I was returning before, but with using a smart pointer instead.

Comment: @LewisElliott: Of course the answerer also meant you to update the return type of the function.

Comment: It seems you don't understand **why** you need a smart pointer and are trying to do this because *someone on the Internet* told you to. What they told you happens to be good advice but if you understand *why* that is good advice, you probably won't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your function:

```
BinaryTree::Node* BinaryTree::copyHelper(const Node* other) { ...}
```

It returns a `BinaryTree::Node*`, and it should be returning a `unique_ptr<Node>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree::Node> BinaryTree::copyHelper(const Node* other) { ...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ahah. You can't convert a `unique_ptr<T>` to a `T*`. They're not the same type, and they don't have the same semantics particularly when they get copied. This is why `unique_ptr<T>` doesn't have a conversion operator to `T*`. `T*` isn't a class, so you can't rely on polymorphism to do the work for you like you can with returning a subclass of the declared return type (and in fact `unique_ptr`'s semantic differences would mean that subclassing would be the wrong relationship anyway).

So you don't have a choice here - you have to return a `unique_ptr<T>` and have your callers deal with the consequences as they need to know it's a `unique_ptr<T>` and behaves like one. If you feel this is too much of a burden, I suggest reading up on smart pointers to understand better what they are and what they do for you.

You might also need to consider if it's the correct kind of smart pointer class, as maybe `shared_ptr<T>` has more suitable semantics for you.

Comment: *You can't convert a `unique_ptr<T>` to a `T*`*. While you *shouldn't* you clearly can. There is no conversion, but `unique_ptr<T>` has a `release` member function that will yield ownwership of the pointer. That being said, whether you want to do that or not is a completely different issue.

Comment: That's why I didn't call it a conversion.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it `copyHelper` is an internal function, not part of the interface. If that is so, then the simplest solution is changing the signature to return a `unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer.

The alternative is calling `release` on the `unique_ptr` inside `copyHelper` to give up ownership, and let the caller reclaim it in it's own `unique_ptr` (for that you will need to use `reset`), but there is no point in going through a raw pointer when you are going to store it in a `unique_ptr` in the very next step.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it, but as all of my other functions are expecting a raw pointer it has created many more errors. I think I'm going to leave my two parasoft erros in my solution, I only lose two marks for them out of a possible 100.

Comment: @LewisElliott if you find answers useful you can also upvote them. I see plenty of useful answers here...

Comment: They are useful, but I don't have 15 reputation yet, Im new. so I cannot upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function and the value you actually return have different types, and there exists no implicit conversion between what you return and what your function is declared to return.